# how do i pass multiple string value to an ibatis custom query

Tags: java, ibatis

```
SELECT  *from ks,lk
WHERE     (Category_Code = #category#) AND Item_Code = #item_code#)
AND  (Return_Data.Institution_Code NOT IN (#bankCodes#))
```

I want to pass a collection of many value in the **not in clause**. How do I pass it in Java? I have tried `bankcodes="0000006"+","+"0000001";` but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you show us some of your code/work?

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of the Dynamic SQL features of MyIbatis (lookup Dynamic SQL in the userguide):

```
SELECT  *from ks,lk
WHERE     (Category_Code = #category#) AND Item_Code = #item_code#)
AND  (Return_Data.Institution_Code NOT IN 

  <foreach item="item" index="index" collection="bankCodes"
    open="(" separator="," close=")">
      #{item}
  </foreach>
)
```